# Rotation in react application

Tags: css, react-native, animation, react-redux, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a game where I have to move the plane in circular motion. However, when it reaches 90 degree or certain angle it still points in same direction as it is still image. I want to update the position on a circle with the state of react but image should also move and not point in same direction. [aeroplane move circular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHsDf.png)

Currently the head is in east direction, at 0 degree. Now if the react state has value 90 degree i want it to move on this circle 90 degree but also now point upwards in north direction . Anyhelp?

Yes I tried it but does not seem to be working. I was using canvas earlier.....................

```
class Louie extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    this.rotateImage = this.rotateImage.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    this.props.dispatch(getStats());
    this.canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = require("../../Images/louie-front.png");
    this.image.id = "lpl-head";
    this.image.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
    this.camera = {};
    this.camera.x = 0;
    this.camera.y = 0;
    this.scale = 1.0;
    this.obj = [];
    this.t = {};
    this.t.angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2; //start angle
    this.t.radius = document.getElementById("louie-canvas").offsetHeight - 100;
    this.t.x = Math.cos(this.t.angle) * this.t.radius; // start position x
    this.t.y = Math.sin(this.t.angle) * this.t.radius; //start position y
    this.t.circumference = this.t.radius * 2 * Math.PI; //curcumfrence
    this.t.start = Date.now();

    this.obj.push(this.t);

    this.draw();
  }

  draw = () => {
    this.update();
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    this.ctx.save();

    this.ctx.translate(
      0 - (this.camera.x - this.canvas.width / 2),
      0 - (this.camera.y - this.canvas.height / 2)
    );
    this.ctx.scale(this.scale, this.scale);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.obj.length; i++) {
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.arc(0, 0, this.obj[i].radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      this.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = "#949494";
      this.ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
      this.ctx.shadowColor = "#080808";
      this.ctx.shadowOffsetX = 10;
      this.ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
      this.ctx.stroke();
      this.ctx.drawImage(
        this.image,
        this.obj[i].x - (window.innerWidth * 4) / 100,
        this.obj[i].y - (window.innerWidth * 3) / 100,

        (window.innerWidth * 8) / 100,
        (window.innerHeight * 10) / 100
      );
    }
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#ab377a";
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(this.draw);
  };

  update = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.obj.length; i++) {
      var angle = this.props.headDegree;
      this.obj[i].x = this.obj[i].radius * Math.cos((angle * Math.PI) / 180);
      this.obj[i].y = this.obj[i].radius * Math.sin((angle * Math.PI) / 180);
    }
  };

  rotateImage = (angle) => {
    this.image.style.transform = `rotateZ(${angle * 3}deg)`;
  };
```

Comment: Did you try the css ```transform: rotate(90deg);``` property ? 
Resource : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Yes I tried it but does not seem to be working.

Comment: I was using Canvas ealier. But does not seem to be working

Comment: just to be more understanding ... this is what you want . ?
https://prnt.sc/ufge82

Comment: Something like the plane reaches 90 and the head points upwards..and this happens with react state